# Laravel before today rule... how to do

Tags: php, laravel

For this rule I am getting an error `syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'`

```
public static $rules = array(
    'first_name' => 'required|alpha-dash',
    'last_name' => ' required|alpha-dash',
    'media_release' => 'required|boolean',
    'birthday' => 'before:' . date('Y-m-d')

);
```

I can't figure out why this won't work. I'm running Laravel 4.2.12

Comment: You cannot use an expression in a property declaration (prior to PHP 5.6). You need to set that up in the constructor - otherwise it can only be a static value.

Comment: That's known as a "constant scalar expression" and we just got the ability to use them recently. They're a common problem http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I am on php 5.5.9. Thanks!

Comment: What I can't find right now is the official doc where they are mentioned as not working. It might have been in the OOP Properties manual, but removed for 5.6? I don't know - I've found it successfully several times before.

Comment: Now I see it - I had been overlooking it in the paragraph: "_. This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated._" http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use a function when defining class member variables. You'll have to move that part to your constructor:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public static $rules = array(
        'first_name' => 'required|alpha-dash',
        'last_name' => ' required|alpha-dash',
        'media_release' => 'required|boolean'
    );
    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$rules['birthday'] = 'before:' . date('Y-m-d');
    }
```

**EDIT:**

The above solution may not work in Laravel. You may have to use a "Custom Validator" instead:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules

**UPDATE:**

Looks like Laravel 5 introduced a better solution. See the answer by Fernando, below.

Comment: Overwriting the contructor in my model class definition works as you described for Laravel. There is no constructor defined in the parent that takes 0 arguments. I am assuming it is not overwriting the parent class constructor which takes 2 arguments. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It probably IS overwriting the parent constructor. Adjust this constructor to accept those 2 arguments, and call `parent::__construct($arg1, $arg2)` somewhere in this constructor to maintain the parent.

Comment: Thanks! You are correct, I don't know why I couldn't type in the right search terms when checking. Overloading constructors is NOT supported in PHP.

Answer (score 45):

try this:

```
'birthday' => 'date_format:Y-m-d|before:today',
```

bye

Comment: Works for me. Tested with "after:now" as well

Answer (score 34):

Just for future users:

Laravel 5 using form requests:

```
'birthday' => 'before:today',    // Doesn't accept today date
'birthday' => 'before:tomorrow', // Accept today date
```

Comment: Laravel (or php) handle ```'date_format:Y|before:today'``` by considering the current year always false (because it's the today year).
So to solve this I postponed it to *tomorrow* and that did it :) (thanks to your reply)

Comment: @ThomasLAURENT I'm glad that this helped you :)
Have a nice coding!

Comment: I have been searching for a while and I can't find the date validation options. Is there only `today, yesterday,tomorrow` or is there more?

Comment: Hey!
Since this validator uses `strtotime` you should be able to use these formats:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: @FrenchMajesty you can pass any custom date to date validation. Ex: `date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s|before:2019-08-22 00:00:00`

Comment: You can use `before_or_equal:today`

Answer (score 9):

I recommend you to add a `before` and an `after` statement for **birthdays**.

```
'birthday' => date_format:Y-m-d|before:today|after:1900-01-01
```

You'll avoid entries like `1111-1-1` because no one alive was born before the year 1900.